# I dont want by authenticated user to delete cognito account. How can i stop user from deleting his account if auth user uses back channel process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using amplify to host my website(related to finances).

I have used cognito for authentication of a user.

In browser, user can easily get appClient id, user pool id and identity id

Backchannel process is create dummy html js page. User log in the app and after successful login, user used DeleteUserCommand to delete his account.

```
var params = { AccessToken:"<accessToken>" }
const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({"<aws-region>"})
var data = await client.send(new DeleteUserCommand(params))
```

Using above three lines user can delete their account.

I don't want user to have access to delete their account.

[Aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteUser.html) says i cannot restrict user from deleting his account. Is it possible to not allow user to delete his account.

Thankyou in advance.

I have already used aws hosting environment variable to store appClient id so that user can not access it. But on inspect, user can still see it.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, because there's clean-up code I want to run before deleting a user from Cognito. The link you provided shows that the command can return a FrobiddenException if an AWS WAF rule prevents the request from being carried out. I haven't tried it myself, but I would look into setting up WAF with Cognito and seeing if you can block DeleteUser requests that way. If that works, you can create your own API to allow user deletion, and attach any surrounding logic in that API's handler.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Roy you can achieve that by using AWS WAF. Using Firewall for your pool requests allows you to create a specific rule to deny `DeleteUser`, or any other operation.

To do this, first you create a WEB ACL with a rule to deny the `DeleteUser` operation based on the header content. Here is a example in SAM Yaml:

```yaml
  BlockDeleteUserACL:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACL
    Properties:
      DefaultAction:
        Allow: {}  # You want to keep allowing other operations
      Scope: REGIONAL
      VisibilityConfig:
        CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        MetricName:  BlockDeleteUserACL
        SampledRequestsEnabled: true
      Rules:
        - Action:
            Block: {}  # Block when statement matches
          Name:  BlockDeleteUserRule
          Priority: 0
          Statement:
            ByteMatchStatement:
              FieldToMatch:
                SingleHeader:
                  name: x-amz-target  
              PositionalConstraint: CONTAINS
              SearchString: DeleteUser  # Search for DeleteUser in header
              TextTransformations:
                - Priority: 0
                  Type: NONE
          VisibilityConfig:
            CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
            MetricName:  BlockDeleteUserRule
            SampledRequestsEnabled: true
```

Now you have to associate this ACL to your user pool. If you are using SAM Yaml you can do something like this:

```yaml
   BlockDeleteUserAssociation :
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation
    Properties:
      ResourceArn: !GetAtt UserPool.Arn  # Your user pool resource ARN
      WebACLArn: !GetAtt  BlockDeleteUserACL.Arn
```

Finally, you can create a route in your backend to execute whatever you want, then use `AdminDeleteUser` to delete the desired user.